# golang/glog created hundreds of tiny files on my server

Tags: go, glog

I am using glog in my app that is deployed in a docker container and it has created hundreds of tiny files and I am wondering why and how to stop it.  Here is a small sample of my directory listing.

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 urbncat urbncat         20 Jun 27 18:40 InventoryProcessor.32c423b6e305.urbncat.log.INFO.20170626-134018.246-1498528861.gz-1498536061.gz-1498546861.gz-1498550462.gz-1498582862.gz-1498590064.gz-1498608095.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 urbncat urbncat         20 Jun 27 20:14 InventoryProcessor.32c423b6e305.urbncat.log.INFO.20170626-134018.246-1498528861.gz-1498536061.gz-1498546861.gz-1498550462.gz-1498582862.gz-1498590064.gz-1498611709.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 urbncat urbncat          0 Jun 27 23:34 InventoryProcessor.32c423b6e305.urbncat.log.INFO.20170626-134018.246-1498528861.gz-1498536061.gz-1498546861.gz-1498550462.gz-1498586462.gz-1498593665.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 urbncat urbncat         20 Jun 27 18:40 InventoryProcessor.32c423b6e305.urbncat.log.INFO.20170626-134018.246-1498528861.gz-1498536061.gz-1498546861.gz-1498550462.gz-1498586462.gz-1498593665.gz-1498604479.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 urbncat urbncat         20 Jun 27 18:40 InventoryProcessor.32c423b6e305.urbncat.log.INFO.20170626-134018.246-1498528861.gz-1498536061.gz-1498546861.gz-1498550462.gz-1498586462.gz-1498593665.gz-1498608095.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 urbncat urbncat         20 Jun 27 20:14 InventoryProcessor.32c423b6e305.urbncat.log.INFO.20170626-134018.246-1498528861.gz-1498536061.gz-1498546861.gz-1498550462.gz-1498586462.gz-1498593665.gz-1498611709.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 urbncat urbncat          0 Jun 27 23:34 InventoryProcessor.32c423b6e305.urbncat.log.INFO.20170626-134018.246-1498528861.gz-1498536061.gz-1498546861.gz-1498550462.gz-1498590064.gz-1498597268.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 urbncat urbncat         54 Jun 27 14:04 InventoryProcessor.32c423b6e305.urbncat.log.INFO.20170626-134018.246-1498528861.gz-1498536061.gz-1498546861.gz-1498550462.gz-1498590064.gz-1498597268.gz-1498604479.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 urbncat urbncat         20 Jun 27 14:04 InventoryProcessor.32c423b6e305.urbncat.log.INFO.20170626-134018.246-1498528861.gz-1498536061.gz-1498546861.gz-1498550462.gz-1498590064.gz-1498597268.gz-1498608095.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 urbncat urbncat         20 Jun 27 20:14 InventoryProcessor.32c423b6e305.urbncat.log.INFO.20170626-134018.246-1498528861.gz-1498536061.gz-1498546861.gz-1498550462.gz-1498590064.gz-1498597268.gz-1498611709.gz
```

Comment: just guessing that your log rotation/compression rules are wrong. Old logs should be compressed - so InventoryProcessor.32c423b6e305.urbncat.log.INFO.20170626-134018.246 should become: InventoryProcessor.32c423b6e305.urbncat.log.INFO.20170626-134018.246-1498528861.gz.  In your case even the already gzipped files are getting gzipped over and over again.

Comment: But glog does not do that so you think the log rotation on the server is wrong?

Comment: It's the first thing I would check

Comment: After looking into it I believe you are right and that I will pass this on to my DevOps guys :)  Thanks!